# Trying to covert timestamp to date causes error

Tags: oracle

```
select to_date('25-MAY-20 12.10.12.320000 PM', 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi:ss pm') from dual;
```

getting the error

> "am or pm required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle only stores precision up to seconds in a date type.  If you want fractional seconds (e.g. milliseconds) you will need to use a timestamp column.  But in any case, your current format mask is wrong.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('25-Feb-20 12.10.12.320000 PM', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.ff6 pm')
FROM dual
```

## Demo

Comment: Thank you. further converted time stamp to char and to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your timestamp into char and then convert to date.
Example with systimestamp:

```
select to_date(
         to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mon-yy hh:mi:ss PM')
       , 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi:ss PM') 
from dual;
```